# Dispatching custom events

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have version 0.9.0.1 of the typescript compiler installed in my VS 2012 Update 3.

I want to dispatch a custom event but the ambient variable declared in lib.d.ts does not expose the expected constructor signatures.

When I use

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("my:event:type", { detail: { some: "data"} });
window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

the type script compiler complains, because according to him, only

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent();
```

is correct.

The latter is erroneous according to Chrome 27 and Aurora 24.02, due to "missing arguments"

MDN also lists the actually-correct-but-not-for-typescript constructor signatures.

My thinking was now to add the known-correct constructor signature to the ambient variable declaration, but without touching the shipped lib.d.ts file. Would this technically be possible? I could not come up with the correct syntax for it, and the language specification did not mention how to merge two such declarations.

Alternatively, I simply edited lib.d.ts, which after a restart of the IDE provided me with the updated signature. Nevertheless, I'd rather not tamper with 3rd-party files in such a way.

Last, is there some other mechanism I (sh|c)ould use to write type script code that dispatches a custom event?

(Update: Restarting the IDE reloads lib.d.ts correctly. Also, corrected made-up event type name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't part of `lib.d.ts` is that Internet Explorer doesn't support this object in IE10.

If the `CustomEvent` definition was purely an interface, you would be able to extend it thus:

```
interface CustomEvent {
    new(eventType: string, data: {});
}
```

But the `CustomEvent` constructor is actually defined in a variable declaration, which you can't extend:

```
declare var CustomEvent: {
    prototype: CustomEvent;
    new(): CustomEvent;
}
```

You can use this (nasty looking) work around to get hold of custom events while you wait for Internet Explorer / the TypeScript library to be updated.

```
class StandardsCustomEvent {
    static get(eventType: string, data: {}) {
        var customEvent = <any>CustomEvent;
        var event = new customEvent(eventType, data);
        return <CustomEvent> event;
    }
}

var x = StandardsCustomEvent.get("myevent",  { detail: { some: "data"} });
```

This fixes your compiler warnings - but won't make it work in IE10 or older - you would need to polyfill.

Comment: Defining a TypeScript type the constructor of which does *not* return an object of that type is indeed nasty...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing all of this:

- Use the --nolib option on build
- Add a local copy of the lib.d.ts
- Patch in the expected constructor signatures
- Add a polyfill for IE <= 11 as proposed by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

Answer (score 0):

```
var event = <CustomEvent>(new (<any>CustomEvent)('specifiedEvent'))
```

Might be a solution. Nice looking and tricky.